# Cron expression to run azure function every day at 1 am

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I'm working on azure function time trigger using visual studio. I have set cron expression "TimerTrigger("0 1 * * *")" to run my azure function every day at 1 am. after running the function locally it is showing correct 'next 5 occurrences'

[image: next 5 occurrences]

but after deploying the azure function on azure portal is showing 'invalid cron expression'

[image: invalid cron expression]

what can be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a "0", the correct one should be "0 0 1 * * * ".

A [CRON expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions) includes **six** fields:

{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}

Comment: @RonaldAbellano, yes, you're right. The hour is 24hour format.